# AIR for iOS nativeApplication.idleThreshold works for desktop only?

Tags: ios, air

Using the built in nativeApplication.idleThreshold to determine inactivity on an AIR application. Works great when I target the desktop. However, unable to get it to work when I publish to iOS. Does anyone have a clue why?

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.idleThreshold=4;
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.USER_IDLE, function(event:Event) {
                    if (_mode != Const.IDLE) {
                        _mode=Const.IDLE;
                        sendNote();
                    }
                });
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.USER_PRESENT, function(event:Event) {
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because it's meant to be that way "by design".

If you check the documentation for "userIdle" or "userPresent", you'll see this line:
"This event is not dispatched on mobile devices or AIR for TV devices"

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:userIdle

So for some reason I can't understand, they didn't think it was necessary to implement those two events in mobile apps (iOS, Android, Blackberry).

But I think they'd be useful in mobile apps too, so I've filed a feature request.

Please vote here so they consider implementing it:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3648849

BTW, in your sample code you're using a 4 second threshold, which wouldn't work anyway even in desktop, since the minimum is 5.